# Snowflake snowpark python worksheet udf

Tags: python, function, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, worksheet

@udf(name='a_plus_b', input_types=[IntegerType(), IntegerType()], return_type=IntegerType(), is_permanent=False, replace=True)
def a_plus_b(a: int, b: int) -> int:
return a+b

def main(session: snowpark.Session):

```
df.with_column('Somme',a_plus_b( col('a'),col('b') ) )

return df
```

here is the error in my @udf registration.
Traceback (most recent call last): Worksheet, line 8, in <module> File "snowflake/snowpark/functions.py", line 6693, in udf session = session or snowflake.snowpark.session._get_active_session() File "snowflake/snowpark/session.py", line 179, in _get_active_session raise SnowparkClientExceptionMessages.SERVER_NO_DEFAULT_SESSION() snowflake.snowpark.exceptions.SnowparkSessionException: (1403): No default Session is found. Please create a session before you call function 'udf' or use decorator '@udf'.

can someone helpme me please.

Comment: Please paste your code in code blocks (use the `{}` button) and remove the extra backslashes.

Comment: You would use the @UDF decorator when doing Python development on your local system. This means that you don't have a default session (per the error message) so you need to create one. See https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/python/creating-session for details. If doing development using Python Worksheets, you would have a default session as reflected in your main definition, but you would not use the UDF decorator in a Python worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def main(session: snowpark.Session):

     @udf(name='a_plus_b', input_types=[IntegerType(), IntegerType()], return_type=IntegerType(), is_permanent=False, replace=True)
     def a_plus_b(a: int, b: int) -> int: return a+b

     df.with_column('Somme',a_plus_b( col('a'),col('b') ) )

return df
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).